# Calculating object position from image processing

Tags: image-processing, geometry, position, perspective

I am looking for an efficient way to calculate the position of an oject on a surface based on an image taken from a certain perspective.

Let me explain a little further.
There is an object on a rectangular flat surface.
I have a picture taken of this setup with the camera positioned at one of the corners of the surface area at a rather low angle.
On the picture I will thus see a somewhat distorted, diamond-shaped view of the surface area and somewhere on it the object.

Through some image processing I do have the coordinates of the object on the picture but now have to calculate the actual position of the object on the surface.

So I do know that the center of the object is at the pixel-coordinates (x/y) on the picture and I know the coordinates of the 4 reference points that represent the corners of the area.

How can I now calculate the "real world" position of the object most efficiently (x and y coordinates on the surface)?

Any input is highly appreciated since I have worked so hard on this I can't even think straight anymore.

Best regards,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

You have to find a perspective transformation.

[Here](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~cwren/interpolator/) you may find an explanation and code in Matlab

HTH!

Comment: Thanks a lot belisarius, I had never heard that term before but that will get me started!

Answer (score 1):

How good is your linear algebra? A perspective transformation can be described by a [homography matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography). You can estimate that matrix using the four corner points, invert it and the calculate the world coordinates of every pixel in your image.

Or you can just let [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/calib3d_camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) do that for you.